# What does "expose"=true mean in symfony?

Tags: symfony

What does the options={"expose"=true} mean in @Route() in a symfony controller?

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="notification_show", options={"expose"=true}, requirements={"id": "\d+"})
     */
    public function showAction(Request $request, Notification $notification)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Probably [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html#generating-uris)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use FOSJsRoutingBundle, you need this option in order to be able to generate route in JavaScript, like this one :

```
var homeUrl = Routing.generate('home');
```